# Why does TIOCSTI take pointer to char instead of char?

Tags: c, linux, ioctl

When it just want 1 byte anyway, Why is it

```c
ioctl(int fd, TIOCSTI, const char *argp)
```

? Wouldn't

```c
ioctl(int fd, TIOCSTI, const char argp)
```

make more sense? and be faster? (it wouldn't need to follow a pointer, and the caller wouldn't need to make a valid pointer either)

Why was pointer-to-char chosen over char?

Comment: In this context, would a pointer to char allow passing what is in effect a char array?  If so, that would be more efficient.

Comment: The [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) says "The third argument is an untyped **pointer** to memory. It's traditionally `char *argp` (from the days before `void *` was valid C), and will be so named for this discussion." By taking a pointer, the second argument can specify the behaviour in a flexible way.

Comment: I suspect this is historical. All the `ioctl` arguments are either `int` or a pointer, and these were the same size in the original Unix implementation.

Comment: I doubt it's possible to find any documentation on the original design decisions. So any answers will undoubtedly be speculation.

Comment: @Barmar years ago (2016 maybe?) I asked a question about the Nagle algorithm/TCP_NODELAY, and actually got an answer from John Nagle himself, the guy who invented it in 1984. Wouldn't be impossible that 1 of the people involved in the TIOCSTI design found my question and answered it

Comment: @Barmar actually that was 8 February 2015, here's the thread https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_talk:Nagle/Archive_2015-09-01#%22Nagle's_Algorith%22,_can_it_handle_length%3E65535?

Answer (score 1):

`ioctl` does a lot of things, but in all cases it passes some kind of data block to, or returns a data block from, a driver that depends on the file descriptor.

The data block is completely different depending on the command. Although `TIOCSTI` only needs one character, there are many other `ioctl` commands, such as `TCSETS` which takes a `const struct termios*`. So they designed it so *every* `ioctl` command uses a pointer.

Note that on Linux, the command code itself sets the size of the data block and whether it's a get or set command. `TIOCSTI` evaluates to a number, and some of the bits in that number tell the `ioctl` function that it should send one byte of data to the driver.

Comment: ```So they designed it so every ioctl command uses a pointer``` - no, TCSBRK take int (not pointer to int, just int) - same with TCSBRKP, TCXONC, TCFLSH, TIOCSCTTY, TIOCGPTPEER and TIOCMIWAIT

Comment: .. meanwhile TIOCSETD takes const pointer-to-int :o well that's confusing

Comment: As I mentioned in in a comment, they all take either a pointer or int. And when it was designed, these were the same size.